# g-mean affected by threshold moving?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, statistics, model-evaluations

Is g-mean (geometric mean of sensitivity and specificity) a better evaluation metric than other metrics (that are derived from the confusion matrix) in situations where decision thresholds are not the same? I want to compare other existing works but they have different decision thresholds than mine and also they have not provided AUROC and AUPR scores.

Comment: Why should it matter that the thresholds aren’t the same? If you’re going to classify an input, part of your responsibility is finding a good threshold. If you picked a bad threshold, the assessment of your performance should penalize you for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, g-mean will not perform better than other confusion matrix metrics. G-mean will perform in a similar way since g-mean is a function of two other confusion matrix metrics: sensitivity (i.e., true positive rate or recall) and specificity (i.e., true negative rate).

Different threshold values can be compared with g-mean to find which threshold performs best.